# Setting image in Alert dialog which comes from other activity

Tags: android

I have an alert dialog, in that i have a button and an image view, on click of button an activity is fired which contains a gallery in which there are pictures, when clicked on a picture i have to show it in that image view. please guide.

Comment: Can you give us some more details about your question...because I don't really understand what you want to do.

Comment: thing is that in an alert dialog there are two things one button and one image view. Now when i click on that button a new page will appear which will contain images. i have to choose a image from this page, which will go and set in that image view which was in the alert dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivityForResult` to start the new `Activity` from the button and `Override` the `onActivityResult` method in your `Activity` where is placed your `alert dialog`.And depending on the result which your `Activity` returns, you can set the chosen image.